# Git Conflict Markers showing a different file update

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlab

We are merging Master into Feature Branch and suddenly, we observed some files where conflicts appeared.

1. These files were never moved to Master
2. Conflict marker in files were showing Head in correct part but Master markers showing content from a completely different file.

Not sure how 2. is possible? we are truly scared now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApexPage xmlns=http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata>
<<<<<<<< HEAD:salesforce_sfdx/force-app/main/default/pages/xyz.page-meta.xml
    <apiVersion>53.0</apiVersion>
    <label>xyz</label>
========
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <label>abc</label>
>>>>>>>> development:salesforce_sfdx/force-app/main/default/pages/abc.page-meta.xml
</ApexPage>
```

Comment: This does not sound possible, so you'll have to provide more details. Carefully inspect the history of that file in both branches is all I can suggest. If Git is showing that conflict, those changes have to have happened on that file at *some* point.

Comment: Not really, these are two different files. even if changes happened, how can the markers be from different files.

Comment: Different hypothesis... Git has smarts to try to recognize that a file was renamed, and then it applies the changes to the file it thinks it got renamed to. I have a project where I spliced part of a repo into a new repo with a different tree structure, made change in that tree, and then cherry picked commits over, and Git could figure out which files to apply those patches to. It felt like magic, but it worked like a charm in my case and saved me a ton of time. What you have here could be those smarts mis-firing?

Comment: Questions, that may help confirm my theory (although they won't actually prove anything, sorry): are the two pages really similar? And do the two files each exist in only one branch?

Comment: I'd want @torek's opinion on this question, he's likely to know how to figure it out, but I don't know how to invite him to look at this. Maybe a bounty would attract the attention of better experts than me.

Comment: This is a shared repo between different squads and in this scenario, the HEAD file owned by a different squad and development file is from a different squad. one squad wont touch the other file.

Even if the file content is similar, doesnt the git operate based on file name first?

Comment: btw, this happened atleast twice, not once. we are on a GitLab self hosted instance.

Comment: Oxycash, would you be able to run the commands torek has shown in their answers and show us the results?

Comment: Also, can you show the output of `git log --follow --format=oneline --stat development -- abc.page-meta.xml` and `git log --follow --format=oneline --stat HEAD -- xyz.page-meta.xml` (where this last command has to be run from the state you were in when you got the conflict, or else replace HEAD by the right branch name)?

Comment: The TL;DR here is that while you may not have done a rename, Git is inferring from what it sees that a rename happened. Everything else here is about trying to determine why Git is making that inference.

Comment: If you redo the same merge with the option `--find-renames=100%`, do you get the same results? Second question: if you redo it with `--no-renames`, do you still get the same results? The first will tell Git to consider a rename only when the files are identical, and the second tells Git not to consider renames at all.

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding an answer here, with a potential work around inspired by @torek's answer.

It's clear already that the problem is due to Git (incorrectly) inferring that a rename happened, and deciding to act accordingly. It's not clear yet why, but torek's suggestion to use `git diff --find-renames` for troubleshooting lead me to read the manual and discover two options that might help you:

1. You can tell Git to be strict when it's looking for renames, considering only identical files as renames:

   ```
    git merge --find-renames=100% <rest of your merge command>
   ```
2. You can tell Git to turn off rename detection altogether:

   ```
    git merge --no-renames <rest of your merge command>
   ```

The thing you need to know for all this to make sense is that Git only stores snapshots of your whole project tree in each commit. A commit is not actually stored as a change set, but as a full new snapshot. So whenever you merge, cherry pick, view the log, do a diff, all of that is done by diff'ing these snapshots. Renames are no exceptions: the fact that you did `git mv` in a commit is not stored, it's inferred by the diff with the previous commit, or possible between merge bases when there's more than one. And sometimes that inference makes mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

(Note: this isn't really an *answer*, at least not yet.)

What we have in the merge conflict is this information, which I have taken from the two markers:

```
HEAD:salesforce_sfdx/force-app/main/default/pages/xyz.page-meta.xml
development:salesforce_sfdx/force-app/main/default/pages/abc.page-meta.xml
```

This tells us that index slot #2 (`--ours`) has, for this file, the contents taken from `salesforce_sfdx/force-app/main/default/pages/xyz.page-meta.xml` in the `HEAD` commit, and index slot #3 (`--theirs`) has the contents taken from `salesforce_sfdx/force-app/main/default/pages/xyz.page-meta.xml` in the `development` commit.  The file must therefore exist in both commits, and there must be a *merge base* version of that file, which will be in index slot #1.

Several more things would be useful here.  In particular, `merge.conflictStyle` is clearly set to `merge` here.  This hides some information; if it were set to `diff3` we'd get more information.  We can reconstruct this information though.

First, we'd like to know which commit(s) is/are the source of the merge base version of this merge base version.  To find out, run:

```
git merge-base --all HEAD MERGE_HEAD
```

This will spit out a single commit hash ID, if things are ideal, or multiple hash IDs if things are less than ideal.

Second, we'd like to know what's actually in the corresponding lines in the file in index slot #1.  That's easy to obtain: `git show :1:salesforce_sfdx/force-app/main/default/pages/xyz.page-meta.xml` should extract the entire file, which we can then inspect.

If the `git merge-base` command shows multiple commits, it's possible that the merge base is a "virtual commit" (made by `git merge-recursive` or `git merge-ort`, or whichever strategy is being used here).  In this case the merge base itself may contain a merge conflict.

In any case, there are definitely three input files.  If there's only a single merge base, we're in much better shape because we can figure out what those three files are in all three commits using `git diff --find-renames`.  Simply take the merge base hash ID and run:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash> HEAD > /tmp/ours
git diff --find-renames <hash> MERGE_HEAD > /tmp/theirs
```

The two `/tmp` files now contain the diff results, including any detected renames.  The `HEAD` and `development` commits' names for the two output files are the same (`salesforce_sfdx/force-app/main/default/pages/xyz.page-meta.xml`) so the only real question here is what, if anything, was the name of the merge base copy of the file.

Given this additional information, we can then proceed to see why there is a merge conflict here, and whether this represents some sort of Git bug.

Comment: I have successfully created a related but unfortunately not quite representative example. See gist https://gist.github.com/joanise/ab529049e3859b6d3daa6ec7b0f77ab2 where I create two branches with files named like in OP's question. With a cherry pick, I get the same conflict OP observes. It's not really representative, though, because with a merge Git sees the two files are both independently added and there is no conflict. I still don't see how to reproduce the issue with an actual merge.

Comment: I mean, I don't see how to reproduce the issue without using a `git mv` on one of the branches, since OP said the files were never moved to master.

Comment: In any case, looking forward to reading OP's output from the commands you recommend running here. I hope they will shed some light on what they're dealing with. Thanks for taking a stab at this!

Comment: By the way, the point of my gist above was to determine whether Git would a assume that starting from similar files meant a rename had happened. Indeed, in my gist, I create identical files, but with no shared histories or git mv operation, and yet Git still assumed in the cherry pick operation that one was the result of renaming the other. That assumption on Git's part happens to be incorrect, and my hypothesis, still unconfirmed, is that OP's situation stems from something similar.

Comment: @joanis one file is from master(development is our master) and one is a feature branch (HEAD in my case).  I will share the outputs for suggested commands tomorrow.

Comment: Reading the manual for `git diff`, `git log`, `git rebase` and `git merge`, which all have the `--find-renames` option, I notice the default threshold is 50%! That seems very low. If I understand correctly, a commit that deletes a file and add a file that is 50% the same will be detected as a rename in the future. That's a much lower threshold than I would have expected!

Comment: @joanis: yes, I don't know if 50% was chosen after careful testing and analysis or, as I suspect, Linus just yanked it out of his <insert part of anatomy>.  It works fairly well in C source and documentation files, but it could misfire on files with a lot of boilerplate, such as (wait for it) ... XML.

Comment: Well @torek thank you for this answer. This is what I was looking for. I believe we are now leaving this question in a state that it will help future users of Git in similar situations, whether it solve's OP specific case or not. Awarding bounty.

Comment: I have another situation now but that matches the renaming constraint. XML file renamed and some minor changes done. so thats nearly 70% of matching content. 

is there a way to force everything to get recognized as new file and avoid this 50% constraint?

Comment: and is there a way to actually see if git is treating some file as renamed? or it is --find-renames?

Comment: Use the `--find-renames` option with `git diff`, yes. (You can add `--name-status` and/or `--diff-filter=R` to see just the file names and status letters, which includes the similarity index at which the rename is detected and/or to filter out all but the renames.) Note that `git diff br1...br2` (three dots) will diff from merge base to the right-hand branch tip commit before merging, so you can predict problems with `git diff -M --name-status --diff-filter=R br1...br2` and `git diff -M --name-status --diff-filter=R br2...br1`before starting the merge.